# Global hooking of registry using Delphi detours in C++ Builder

Tags: registry, c++builder, detours, setwindowshookex

I am trying to use Detours to hook registry calls using global hooks i use this code but it keeps on giving me exception when i run other C++ Builder apps.
I don't know what exactly should I pass to `SetWindowsHookEx` as hook type.

The idea here is that i want to capture any exe that opens a specific reg key for example `SOFTWARE\\CloudBackendServices` so I am creating this hook here and from another application opens this reg key but whenever I run the other app it crashes with access violation in DllHook.dll. The error is raised when i attach the widechar "RegOpenKeyExW" version of RegOpenKeyEx but when i use the ansistring version no errors at all but the hook does not capture anything.

What am i doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

Dll code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <System.Win.Registry.hpp>
#include "DDetours.hpp"
#include "ClangCpp.h"

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
#define DLLExport __stdcall __declspec(dllexport)

unique_ptr<TStringList> str(new TStringList);
TMemo *Logger = NULL;
HHOOK hKeyHook;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef LSTATUS (*THookedRegOpenKeyExA)(HKEY hKey,LPCSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef LSTATUS (*THookedRegOpenKeyExW)(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef LSTATUS (*THookedRegOpenKeyEx)(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
THookedRegOpenKeyExA HookedRegOpenKeyExA;
THookedRegOpenKeyExW HookedRegOpenKeyExW;
THookedRegOpenKeyEx HookedRegOpenKeyEx;

LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyExA(HKEY hKey,LPCSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyExW(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyEx(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) void InstallDetour()
{
//BeginHooks();

if (HookedRegOpenKeyEx == nullptr)
    HookedRegOpenKeyEx = (THookedRegOpenKeyEx)InterceptCreate(&RegOpenKeyEx, &MyRegOpenKeyEx);

//if (HookedRegOpenKeyExA == nullptr)
//  HookedRegOpenKeyExA = (THookedRegOpenKeyExA)InterceptCreate(&RegOpenKeyExA, &MyRegOpenKeyExA);
//
//if (HookedRegOpenKeyExW == nullptr)
//  HookedRegOpenKeyExW = (THookedRegOpenKeyExW)InterceptCreate(&RegOpenKeyExW, &MyRegOpenKeyExW);
//
//EndHooks();

str->Add("Reg Hook Installed");
str->SaveToFile("logfile.txt");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) void UninstallDetour()
{
//BeginUnHooks();
if (HookedRegOpenKeyExA != nullptr)
    {
    InterceptRemove(HookedRegOpenKeyExA);
    HookedRegOpenKeyExA = nullptr;
    }

if (HookedRegOpenKeyExW != nullptr)
    {
    InterceptRemove(HookedRegOpenKeyExW);
    HookedRegOpenKeyExW = nullptr;
    }
//EndUnHooks();
str->Add("Reg Hook Uninstalled");
str->SaveToFile("logfile.txt");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyExA(HKEY hKey,LPCSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult)
{
//String Key = lpSubKey;
//if (Pos("SOFTWARE\\CloudBackendServices",Key) != 0)
    Logger->Lines->Add(lpSubKey);
//Application->ProcessMessages();
//return RegOpenKeyExA(hKey,lpSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyExW(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult)
{
//String Key = lpSubKey;

//if (Pos("SOFTWARE\\CloudBackendServices",Key) != 0)
    Logger->Lines->Add(lpSubKey);

//Application->ProcessMessages();
//return RegOpenKeyExW(hKey,lpSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LSTATUS MyRegOpenKeyEx(HKEY hKey,LPCWSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM samDesired,
Winapi::Windows::PHKEY phkResult)
{
//String Key = lpSubKey;

//if (Pos("SOFTWARE\\CloudBackendServices",Key) != 0)
    Logger->Lines->Add(lpSubKey);
//return RegOpenKeyExW(hKey,lpSubKey,ulOptions,samDesired,phkResult);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) void SetControl(TMemo* aLogger, HHOOK aKeyHook)
{
Logger = aLogger;
Logger->Lines->Add("Logger Assigned");
hKeyHook = aKeyHook;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) */int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
if (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH == reason)
{
str->Clear();
InstallDetour();
}
else if (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH == reason)
{
UninstallDetour();
}

 return 1;
}
```

Main Hook app:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "MainU.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
hDll = LoadLibrary(L"DllHook.dll");

if (hDll == NULL)
    throw Exception("Load dll error");

KeyEvent = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(hDll, "KeyEvent");

if (KeyEvent == NULL)
    throw Exception("KeyEvent function error");

DoSetControl = (TSetControl)GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetControl");

if (DoSetControl == NULL)
    throw Exception("SetControl function error");

hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,(HOOKPROC) KeyEvent, hDll, 0);
DoSetControl(Logger, hKeyHook);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
{
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyHook);
FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
SetRootKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\CloudBackendServices",false);
CloseKey();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Will Windows actually allow that? If so, that's scarry.

Comment: All of your function pointer typedefs and replacement hook functions are missing the WINAPI (__stdcall) calling convention (the compiler's default is __cdecl). Also, `HookedRegOpenKeyEx` will never work, since there is no function named `RegOpenKeyEx`, only `RegOpenKeyExA` and `RegOpenKeyExW` exist. `RegOpenKeyEx` is a preprocessor macro that maps to one of those functions. `HookedRegOpenKeyEx` needs to use ``LPCTSTR` instead of `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: Also, your `Logger` won't work across process boundaries, it will only be valid in the process the initially installs the hook. You need to use an IPC mechanism to have every hooked process send messages back to your main process for logging

Comment: But using a global hook in this manner is the wrong way to hook Registry activity. Write a lower-level filtering driver instead. That is what [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) uses to watch the Registry without injecting into every running process.

Comment: I modified the code a little after i posted this question. But actually RegOpenKeyExW works and it captures the registry calls but for some it does not when I open a registry key from another app created by c++ builder as well it does detect this and put it into a file.

Comment: But the only thing that i can't capture is when i call these lines:  IEApp = CreateOleObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
 IEApp.PS("Visible", (OleVariant)true);
 IEApp.FN("Navigate", (OleVariant)"https://www.google.com"); 
I know that Com object creation some how search for the registry key "InternetExplorer.Application" in Root classes or HKCU but that won't show in my hook logger but it does appear in Process Monitor.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is get the parent process that created a certain Com Object using real time monitoring if there is another way to do so. Appreciate any help, thanks in advance